# VBA Plotting Graph and adjust point width

Tags: excel, vba

I need a small tip. My results are being plotted in a graph. I want the width of the points on the graph to be smaller.

Currently I am using this code, and it works, but I dont want to use the select property, since at the end one point is always ahown selected. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

```
Dim Dots As Long

For Dots = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Dots).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Weight = 0.8
    End With
Next Dots
```

Comment: Why don't you just select something else at the end so that the last point is no longer selected?

Comment: yeah thats an indirect way. I did thought of that but was looking for some neat option

Comment: @Gordon K: I did take your advice and added a  ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select at the end. For one line it suffices and solves my problem currently. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim i As Long

For Dots = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 0.8
    End With
Next
```

The above was based on your code and avoids the selections.

Here's a more direct way:

```
Dim oDot As Object

For Each oDot In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
    With oDot.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 0.8
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I tried your direct solution. Somewhat it still shows an error in the line "With .Format.Line". And as for i, is i defined other than the declaration?

Comment: Please try it again. There was a typo.

Comment: You asked about "i". Yes, it is used beyond the declaration. Look closely at the longest line... near the end you will see this bit: Points(i).Format.Line. That is am "i" in the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works like a charm and indeed the run time improved a lot. Thank you once again.